# How to write down the Lippmann-Schwinger equation for such a problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

Suppose there are three particles, 1, 2, 3. Initially, particle 2 and particle 3 form a bound state. Particle 1 is free. Now we want to study the scattering of particle 1 against the 2-3 bound system.

The total Hamiltonian is

$$  H = T_1 + T_2 + T_3 + V_{12} + V_{13} + V_{23} $$

Let us assume the particles are distinguishable, and the potentials are different.

How to write down the LS equation for such a problem? And how to solve it?